# Determine how many times a Django model instance has been updated

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to find a generic way to get a count of how many times an instance of a model has had any of its fields updated. In other words, in Django, how do I get a count of how many times a specific row in a table has been updated? I'm aiming to show a count of how many updates have been made.

Let's say I have:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField()
    another_field = models.IntegerField()

    ...
```

and I have an instance of the model:

```
my_model = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
```

Is there a way to find out how many times `my_model` has had any of its fields updated? Or would I need to create a field like `update_count` and increment it each time a field is updated? Hopefully there is some kind of mechanism available in Django so I don't have to go that route.

Hopefully this isn't too basic of a question, I'm still learning Django and have been struggling with how to figure this out on my own.

Comment: Use https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic way to get this. As mentioned by [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736787/determine-how-many-times-a-django-model-instance-has-been-updated#comment98151566_55736787) you can use some "versioning package" to track whole history of changes. I've personally used the same suggestion: django-reversion, but there are [other alternatives](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/versioning/).

If you need to track only some fields then you may program some simpler mechanism yourself:

1. create a model/field to track your information
2. use something like [FieldTracker](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker) to track changes to specific fields
3. Create handler post-save signal (or just modify model's `save` method) to save the data

You may also use something like "table audit". I haven't tried anything like that myself but there are some packages for that too:

- https://github.com/StefanKjartansson/django-postgres-audit
- https://github.com/torstenrudolf/django-audit-trigger
- https://github.com/kvesteri/postgresql-audit

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!